# Tooltips Problem with Infragistics UltraToolBar in child window

Tags: c#, infragistics, mdi, childwindow

Currently have an UltraToolBar displaying within a MDI child window currently all the buttons on the bar function but they do not show their tooltips when hovered over. I was wondering if anyone else may have dealt with this problem before and what they did.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the toolbar in Ribbon mode or in old toolbar mode?

If the toolbar is in on a child mdi form, you should probably be merging it into the parent mdi manager.

On your 'main form' you should use a UltraTabbedMdiManager class to open your child MDI windows. Get the main structure of you app set up right and the small stuff with fall out naturally.